# Web scrape page table Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a table from a website, but i am not very familiar with Python. The url is [here](https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/gr/almyros/LGBL/date/2017-4-4)
I would like to get the table in a data.frame format in order to continue my analysis.

Here is the code i have tested :

```
from lxml import html

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

url="https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/gr/almyros/LGBL/date/2017-4-4"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}

req = Request(url=url1, headers=headers) 

html = urlopen(req).read() 

print(html)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

type(soup)

print(soup)

p=soup.find_all('thead')

k=soup.find_all('tbody')

print(k)
```

I don't know how to get the table of daily observations

Comment: Please explain the problem that you currently have.

Comment: In this url i sent, there is a table which i would like  get it. The problem is that i don't know how to do it

Comment: You need to access each `tr` for the rows and then each `td` for each item inside.

Comment: page is dynamic, rendered by JS. There is an API but you need to insert the API key to get the json response

Comment: Hi Nikos, welcome to StackOverflow!  I think the issue that people are having is that your question is pretty broad.  It looks like you've already got some code - where is it going wrong?  How do you know it's wrong?  What behavior do you expect?  If you can narrow down the problem it will be much easier for people to provide useful help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import re
import requests

url="https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/gr/almyros/LGBL/date/2017-4-4"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    p = re.compile(r'point\?apiKey=([a-zA-z0-9]*)&', re.MULTILINE)
    apiKey = re.findall(p, response.text)[0]

    url = 'https://api.weather.com/v1/location/LGBL:9:GR/observations/historical.json'
    payload = {
            'apiKey': apiKey,
            'startDate': '20170404',
            'endDate': '20170404'}

    jsonData = s.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
df = json_normalize(jsonData['observations'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
   blunt_phrase        class clds day_ind  dewPt  expire_time_gmt  feels_like  gust  heat_index  icon_extd   key max_temp min_temp obs_id          obs_name precip_hrly precip_total  pressure pressure_desc pressure_tend primary_swell_direction primary_swell_height primary_swell_period primary_wave_height primary_wave_period qualifier qualifier_svrty   rh secondary_swell_direction secondary_swell_height secondary_swell_period snow_hrly  temp terse_phrase   uv_desc  uv_index  valid_time_gmt  vis water_temp  wc  wdir wdir_cardinal  wspd  wx_icon      wx_phrase
0          None  observation  OVC       N     45       1491263400          44  None          46       2600  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   93                      None                   None                   None      None    46         None       Low         0      1491256200    6       None  44   260             W     5       26         Cloudy
1          None  observation  OVC       N     45       1491267000          44  None          46       2600  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   93                      None                   None                   None      None    46         None       Low         0      1491259800    6       None  44   250           WSW     6       26         Cloudy
2          None  observation  OVC       N     43       1491270600          40  None          45       2600  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   93                      None                   None                   None      None    45         None       Low         0      1491263400    6       None  40   250           WSW     8       26         Cloudy
3          None  observation  OVC       N     41       1491274200          39  None          43       2600  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   93                      None                   None                   None      None    43         None       Low         0      1491267000    6       None  39   250           WSW     6       26         Cloudy
4          None  observation  OVC       N     43       1491277800          39  None          43       2600  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.94          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None  100                      None                   None                   None      None    43         None       Low         0      1491270600    6       None  39   250           WSW     7       26         Cloudy
5          None  observation  SCT       N     39       1491281400          36  None          41       2900  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.94          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   93                      None                   None                   None      None    41         None       Low         0      1491274200    6       None  36   250           WSW     8       29  Partly Cloudy
6          None  observation  FEW       N     39       1491283200          36  None          41       3300  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   93                      None                   None                   None      None    41         None       Low         0      1491276000    6       None  36   260             W     8       33           Fair
7          None  observation  FEW       D     39       1491285000          36  None          41       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   93                      None                   None                   None      None    41         None       Low         0      1491277800    6       None  36   250           WSW     7       34           Fair
8          None  observation  FEW       D     39       1491286800          37  None          41       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   93                      None                   None                   None      None    41         None       Low         1      1491279600    6       None  37   250           WSW     6       34           Fair
9          None  observation  FEW       D     39       1491288600          36  None          41       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   93                      None                   None                   None      None    41         None       Low         1      1491281400    6       None  36   250           WSW     7       34           Fair
10         None  observation  FEW       D     41       1491290400          39  None          43       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   93                      None                   None                   None      None    43         None       Low         1      1491283200    6       None  39   260             W     6       34           Fair
11         None  observation  FEW       D     45       1491292200          46  None          48       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     30.00          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   87                      None                   None                   None      None    48         None       Low         1      1491285000    6       None  46   240           WSW     6       34           Fair
12         None  observation  FEW       D     46       1491294000          50  None          50       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     30.00          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   87                      None                   None                   None      None    50         None       Low         1      1491286800    6       None  50   270             W     2       34           Fair
13         None  observation  FEW       D     46       1491295800          54  None          54       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     30.00          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   77                      None                   None                   None      None    54         None       Low         2      1491288600    6       None  54   250           WSW     2       34           Fair
14         None  observation  FEW       D     48       1491297600          57  None          57       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     30.00          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   72                      None                   None                   None      None    57         None  Moderate         3      1491290400    6       None  57   200           SSW     2       34           Fair
15         None  observation  FEW       D     48       1491299400          57  None          57       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     30.00          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   72                      None                   None                   None      None    57         None  Moderate         3      1491292200    6       None  57    90             E     3       34           Fair
16         None  observation  FEW       D     48       1491301200          57  None          57       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     30.00          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   72                      None                   None                   None      None    57         None  Moderate         4      1491294000    6       None  57   100             E     3       34           Fair
17         None  observation  FEW       D     48       1491303000          59  None          59       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     30.00          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   67                      None                   None                   None      None    59         None  Moderate         5      1491295800    6       None  59    80             E     3       34           Fair
18         None  observation  SCT       D     48       1491304800          59  None          59       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     30.00          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   67                      None                   None                   None      None    59         None  Moderate         4      1491297600    6       None  59    80             E     3       30  Partly Cloudy
19         None  observation  SCT       D     48       1491306600          61  None          61       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     30.00          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   63                      None                   None                   None      None    61         None  Moderate         5      1491299400    6       None  61    70           ENE     6       30  Partly Cloudy
20         None  observation  SCT       D     50       1491308400          61  None          61       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     30.00          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   68                      None                   None                   None      None    61         None  Moderate         5      1491301200    6       None  61    60           ENE     5       30  Partly Cloudy
21         None  observation  SCT       D     48       1491310200          61  None          61       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     30.00          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   63                      None                   None                   None      None    61         None  Moderate         5      1491303000    6       None  61    80             E     6       30  Partly Cloudy
22         None  observation  SCT       D     50       1491312000          61  None          61       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   68                      None                   None                   None      None    61         None  Moderate         5      1491304800    6       None  61    70           ENE     6       30  Partly Cloudy
23         None  observation  SCT       D     50       1491313800          63  None          63       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   63                      None                   None                   None      None    63         None  Moderate         4      1491306600    6       None  63    70           ENE     6       30  Partly Cloudy
24         None  observation  SCT       D     50       1491315600          63  None          63       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   63                      None                   None                   None      None    63         None  Moderate         4      1491308400    6       None  63    70           ENE     6       30  Partly Cloudy
25         None  observation  SCT       D     50       1491317400          63  None          63       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   63                      None                   None                   None      None    63         None  Moderate         3      1491310200    6       None  63   100             E     7       30  Partly Cloudy
26         None  observation  SCT       D     52       1491319200          63  None          63       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.94          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   68                      None                   None                   None      None    63         None  Moderate         3      1491312000    6       None  63    80             E     7       30  Partly Cloudy
27         None  observation  SCT       D     52       1491321000          63  None          63       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.94          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   68                      None                   None                   None      None    63         None       Low         2      1491313800    6       None  63    90             E     7       30  Partly Cloudy
28         None  observation  SCT       D     52       1491322800          63  None          63       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.94          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   68                      None                   None                   None      None    63         None       Low         2      1491315600    6       None  63    90             E     8       30  Partly Cloudy
29         None  observation  SCT       D     52       1491324600          63  None          63       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.94          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   68                      None                   None                   None      None    63         None       Low         1      1491317400    6       None  63    70           ENE     8       30  Partly Cloudy
30         None  observation  SCT       D     50       1491326400          63  None          63       3000  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.94          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   63                      None                   None                   None      None    63         None       Low         1      1491319200    6       None  63   100             E    10       30  Partly Cloudy
31         None  observation  FEW       D     52       1491328200          61  None          61       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.94          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   72                      None                   None                   None      None    61         None       Low         1      1491321000    6       None  61   110           ESE    14       34           Fair
32         None  observation  FEW       D     54       1491330000          59  None          59       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   82                      None                   None                   None      None    59         None       Low         1      1491322800    6       None  59   110           ESE    10       34           Fair
33         None  observation  FEW       D     54       1491331800          59  None          59       3400  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   82                      None                   None                   None      None    59         None       Low         1      1491324600    6       None  59   120           ESE    12       34           Fair
34         None  observation  FEW       N     54       1491333600          57  None          57       3300  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   88                      None                   None                   None      None    57         None       Low         0      1491326400    6       None  57   120           ESE    10       33           Fair
35         None  observation  FEW       N     54       1491335400          57  None          57       3300  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   88                      None                   None                   None      None    57         None       Low         0      1491328200    6       None  57   110           ESE    13       33           Fair
36         None  observation  FEW       N     54       1491339000          55  None          55       3300  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   94                      None                   None                   None      None    55         None       Low         0      1491331800    6       None  55    90             E     5       33           Fair
37         None  observation  FEW       N     52       1491342600          55  None          55       3300  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   88                      None                   None                   None      None    55         None       Low         0      1491335400    6       None  55   130            SE     5       33           Fair
38         None  observation  FEW       N     48       1491346200          50  None          50       3300  LGBL     None     None   LGBL  Volos/Nea Anghia        None         None     29.97          None          None                    None                 None                 None                None                None      None            None   94                      None                   None                   None      None    50         None       Low         0      1491339000    6       None  50   270             W     2       33           Fair
```